# Calculate perimeter in PHP from a form

Tags: php, html, forms, function

I am new to php and are stuck on a function that shall takes values from a html form and calculate the perimeter

```
<form method="post" Action="sida4berakna.php">    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Mata in två värden för att beränka omkretsen</legend>    
        <p><label>Längd: <input name="langd" type="text"></label></p>
        <p><label>Bredd: <input name="bredd" type="text"></label></p>    
        <input type="Submit" value="BERÄKNA">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And this is my php script

```
if(!empty($_GET["langd"])) {
    $langd = $_GET["langd"];
}
else{
    $langd = NULL;
}

if(!empty($_GET["bredd"])) {
    $bredd = $_GET["bredd"];
}    
else{
    $bredd = NULL;
}

function beraknaOmkrets($langd = "langd", $bredd = "bredd") {
    return ($langd * $bredd) / 2;
}

echo beraknaOmkrets();
```

The result I get on the screen after clicking the button is 0.

Comment: Your form uses `method="post"`, but your script accesses the `$_GET` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!empty($_POST["langd"])) {
    $langd = $_POST["langd"];
}
else{
    $langd = NULL;
}

if(!empty($_POST["bredd"])) {
    $bredd = $_POST["bredd"];
}

else{
    $bredd = NULL;
}


function beraknaOmkrets($langd = "langd", $bredd = "bredd") {

    return ($langd * $bredd) / 2;
}

echo beraknaOmkrets($langd,$bredd);
```

Comment: Ah, such a easy mistake! Thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

Change the GET to POST:

```
if(!empty($_POST["langd"])) {
    $langd = $_POST["langd"];
}
else{
    $langd = NULL;
}

if(!empty($_POST["bredd"])) {
    $bredd = $_POST["bredd"];
}

else{
    $bredd = NULL;
}


function beraknaOmkrets($langd = "langd", $bredd = "bredd") {

    return ($langd * $bredd) / 2;
}

echo beraknaOmkrets();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_GET["langd"])) {
$langd = $_GET["langd"];
}
else{
    $langd = NULL;
}

if(!empty($_GET["bredd"])) {
$bredd = $_GET["bredd"];
}

else{
    $bredd = NULL;
}
```

Should be POST instead of GET.
Wich gives us:

```
  if(!empty($_POST["langd"])) {
    $langd = $_POST["langd"];
    }
    else{
        $langd = NULL;
    }

    if(!empty($_POST["bredd"])) {
    $bredd = $_POST["bredd"];
    }

    else{
        $bredd = NULL;
    }
```

Also to make sure youre function sees the variables as integer, use intval.
 href: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

wich gives us:

```
function beraknaOmkrets($langd = "langd", $bredd = "bredd") 
{
    return ( (intval($langd) * intval($bredd)) / 2 );
}
```